# SQLite whereArgs error - xamarin c# android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, cursor

I am trying to `UPDATE WITH NO CONFLICT` an existing value inside my SQLite database in C#.

I get the following error:

[image: error]

This is my code:
[image: code]

Am I missing any arguments inside the `Query` code.
If you need any more code, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the Intellisens tooltip you should see that the second parameter is a ContentValues not a string "ID=?". You are missing also the last parameter (the fifth one)

Comment: So what exactly would i put inside the `Content Values`

Comment: Try using _null_ so it becomes _db.UpdateWithOnConflict(..., null, "Id=?", ....., Conflict.ConflictIgnore);_ See other conflict options here https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Database.Sqlite.Conflict/

Comment: The `Conflict.ConflictIgnore` says this:
`'Conflict' does not contain a definition for 'ConflictIgnore'`

Comment: Yes, my fault. Look at the link posted. There are all the possible options.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? @DEFALT

Comment: I changed the `Conflict.ConflictIgnore` to `Conflict.Ignore` and it is not throwing an error now, I will test asap and let you know.